# How to remove all instances of None from the end of a list?

Tags: python, strip

Python has a string method called `rstrip()`:

```
>>> s = "hello world!!!"
>>> s.rstrip("!")
'hello world'
```

I want to implement similar functionality for a Python list. That is, I want to remove all instances of a given value from the end of a list. In this case, the value is `None`.

Here's some starting examples:

```
[1, 2, 3, None]
[1, 2, 3, None, None, None]
[1, 2, 3, None, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, None, None, 4, 5, None, None]
```

I want the end results to be:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, None, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, None, None, 4, 5]
```

Here's my solution so far:

```
while l[-1] is None:
    l.pop()
```

Comment: That seems like a reasonable enough solution…

Comment: Your solution will throw an `IndexError` if the list is empty or contains only `None`, so add a special case for that.

Comment: Your solution looks pretty good. Popping from the end of a list is O(1) so I think you can't do much better, unless there is a builtin function for that purpose (which isn't the case, afaik)

Comment: To solve @AlexandruDinu's issue, change the `while` condition to check for an empty list before trying to access `l[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the list in-place, then your solution is good, just make sure you handle the case when the list is empty:

```py
while l and l[-1] is None:
    l.pop()
```

If you want to compute a new list, you can adapt your solution into:

```py
def stripNone(l):
    if not l:
        return []
    
    rlim = 0
    for x in reversed(l):
        if x is None:
            rlim += 1
        else:
            break
    
    return l[: len(l) - rlim]
```

There is also [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile), but you have to perform two reversals:

```py
def stripNone(l):
    return list(dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, l[::-1]))[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Two more versions that also work for `None`-only lists:

```
while None in l[-1:]:
    l.pop()
```

```
for x in reversed(l):
    if x is not None:
        break
    l.pop()
```

Benchmarking some solutions on `l = [None] * 10**3`:

```
 83 us  stripNone1
137 us  stripNone2
 60 us  stripNone3
 42 us  stripNone3b
 53 us  stripNone4
 34 us  stripNone5
 19 us  stripNone6
```

Note that `stripNone2` and `stripNone6` have a small flaw: If there's an object among the trailine `None`s that isn't `None` but claims to *equal* `None`, then it'll get removed. Such an object would be highly unusual, though. And perhaps one would actually *want* to remove such an object as well.

Benchmark code:

```
def stripNone1(l):
    while l and l[-1] is None:
        l.pop()

def stripNone2(l):
    while None in l[-1:]:
        l.pop()

def stripNone3(l):
    for x in reversed(l):
        if x is not None:
            break
        l.pop()

def stripNone3b(l):
    pop = l.pop
    for x in reversed(l):
        if x is not None:
            break
        pop()

def stripNone4(l):
    for i, x in enumerate(reversed(l), 1):
        if x is not None:
            del l[-i:]
            break

def stripNone5(l):
    pop = l.pop
    try:
        while (last := pop()) is None:
            pass
        l.append(last)
    except IndexError:
        pass

def stripNone6(l):
    while l:
        chunk = l[-32:]
        if chunk.count(None) < len(chunk):
            while l[-1] is None:
                l.pop()
            break
        del l[-32:]

from timeit import repeat
solutions = stripNone1, stripNone2, stripNone3, stripNone3b, stripNone4, stripNone5, stripNone6
for i in range(3):
    print(f'Round {i+1}:')
    for sol in solutions:
        ls = [[42] * head + [None] * tail
              for _ in range(5)
              for head in range(0, 2001, 200)
              for tail in range(0, 2001, 200)]
        number = len(ls) // 5
        ls = iter(ls)
        time = min(repeat(lambda: sol(next(ls)), number=number)) / number
        print(f'{int(time * 10**6):3d} us  {sol.__name__}')
```

Comment: `None in l[-1:]` is a very slow operation (linear search) that's being executed potentially many times.

Comment: @martineau Not sure why you call a search of a single-element list "linear".

Comment: Because it is of course — what would you call it?

Comment: @martineau Who calls O(1) "linear"?

Comment: I said it's a [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) — a general method for finding an element within a sequence — and am sure there's some general overhead involved in performing one regardless of the length of that sequence.

Comment: @martineau Sure, there are overhead costs, but still odd to say "linear". Together with your "very slow" it sounds like my solution as a whole takes quadratic time, which it doesn't. It's not even twice as slow as the `while l and l[-1] is None` one.

Comment: Alexandru's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71220101/355230) gets my vote. It's also what @Barmar suggested.

Comment: @martineau Added a benchmark. I guess you should complain to Alexandru now that their solution is slow?

Comment: Try your benchmark with some more realistic data (i.e. with varying lengths that are not all `None`) not just one case.

Comment: @martineau Please suggest "more realistic data".

Comment: @martineau I made the test list shorter, barely affected the relative speeds. You said "many times" when you claimed that my first solution is "very slow", hence I use a test case where that "many times" actually happens. Didn't include non-`None` values since they don't really matter, as all solutions only go through the many trailing `None`s and look at at most a single non-`None`. Added a new fastest solution, btw, more than twice as fast as Alexandru's.

Comment: Realistic random data for benchmarking would include equal numbers of *every* kind of possibility since we know nothing about nature of the data it will be applied to. Obviously there will be some limitations on things like length of sequence to be practical.

Comment: @martineau What do you mean with "equal numbers of every kind of possibility"? There are practically *infinitely many* possibilities. Impossible to do all of them. Also, what that sounds like will just result in the same relative speeds I've already shown. But feel free to prove me wrong, write some code that shows it. So far it looks like you're just here to complain and make false accusations and too-vague-to-be-useful suggestions, while I'm doing all the work ... just for you come back and claim that I'm still not doing it right. I feel like I'm being trolled here.

Comment: I said every *kind* of possibility, which in this case would be at least: no `None`s, all `None`s, some `None`s. In the case of a mixture there's all at the beginning or end, and of course somewhere in the middle. Certainly much less that an ∞ number.

Comment: @martineau Those are all the same single kind: `None`s at the end. Just their number varies, from zero to infinity. Whatever is before those `None`s at the end doesn't matter, as naturally none of the solutions look at that before-part at all (except for the single last non-`None` before those `None`s). You mentioned a practical limitation on the length of the sequence. Sequences of millions of elements are easily still practical. And if I take the average of all practical lengths, that's still a length in the millions, which my original benchmark did.

Comment: @martineau I changed the benchmark to use 121 different cases, and of course as expected the results are almost the same. Also added another solution that's over four times faster than Alexandru's.